# I am trying to use 'rails test' and 'rails generate' but I am not able to, I get this output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, frameworks

I am new to ruby on rails and trying to determine how and where to resolve this error, I am not sure why I am getting this output. Assuming this is coming from rails file, I have this in my rails file. I have the default configuration for the rails file but still receiving this error.

````
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        16: from script/rails:11:in `<main>'
        15: from script/rails:11:in `require'
        14: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        13: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        12: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        11: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        10: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
         9: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
         8: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:21:in `perform'
         7: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
         6: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
         5: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require'
         4: from /Users/ellimilt/Documents/Software_Engineering/Practice/Ruby/test/Pensieve/src/PensieveWebsite/rails-root/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
         3: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
         2: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
         1: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support ```



Rails file
````

```
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what could be an issue yet.
You can try to run those commands in bundle.

```
bundle exec rails test
bundle exec rails generate
```

How did you install ruby and rails?

Did you use `rails new app` to create this app?

Can you post content of your `script/rails` file?

Comment: I used my company internal tool to pull the package. I notice with the app I used 'rails new app' to create app I can run the commands in. But not this one. Updated with content of rails file.